# Modifying SharePoint Alert Confirmation Email

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I am adding search alert pro grammatically and when alert is added then system send notification email which tells user to your search alert added successfully , now i want to change the content of this notification email  or disabled to send this email.

Email Content:

'System Account' has subscribed you for alert 'My News Alert' on '' .

You will receive alerts in e-mail. The timing and criteria for the alerts depend on the settings entered when the alert was added.

I have tried looking at alerttemplates.xml but that ONLY modify the email alerts, NOT the alert confirmation email.

Btw, I am using SharePoint 2007.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: you should accept the answer or provide some feedback if it doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

you can use newAlert.Update(false); for more details refer link below

[SharePoint Alert customization](http://sridharu.blogspot.com/2008/12/sharepoint-alert-customization.html)

Comment: This has just helped me a LOT this bit of info! I didn't even know this overload exists and would never have thought to look there. Thanks a LOT.